# Compare HttpClient and Cxf Client to call WebService

Tags: cxf, httpclient

I have the webservices exposed by CXF Framework. And now I wonder about the client, there are 2 methods for me to choose: `HttpClient` and CXF client. 
The highest priority is for web application clients, so would you give advice comparing `HttpClient` and CXF client in order to call web service? (performance, configuration...)

Comment: I think HTTPClient is fine, if you haven't anything special exposed using CXF.